# How to increase internal storage?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I'm using CyanogenMod 13 and rooted. I'm over with my internal storage which was 1GB. Also, all my files are going to internal rather than external.

How to increase the internal storage to install new apps and for other functions?

Answer (score 0):

It's really too low for internal memory. But if you have SD Card, you can move some apps on it and then free more space on your internal storage. Check your camera config whether you're able to save pictures on SD Card. You can also manually move some files (downloads, for example) to the external storage.

Comment: How to move apps?i used link2sd bt didn't worked..unable to do partition with custom recovery..